# In Hadoop User Experience (HUE) When to use [[ldap_servers]]

Tags: ldap, config, cloudera, hue

In HUE's hue.ini config, when to use the [[[ldap_servers]]] config settings? or why those levels of drilldown is present?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? The HUE documentation explains what the LDAP integration is for. For example: http://gethue.com/making-hadoop-accessible-to-your-employees-with-ldap/

Comment: Thanks for the ex. link, I was able to get the LDAP config work.